# Creating HandlerThread in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, audiorecord

I want to do some processing in the AudioRecord loop, that then sets some parameters in the recording loop. But I cannot start the processing thread.

In the UI thread, I start the AsyncTask that sets up the AudioRecord instance:

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
    @Override
    protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
        setupAnalyzer();
    }
}.execute();
```

In the setupAnalyzer() method, I setup a recorder thread and a processing thread:

```
private RecognizerThread recognizerThread;
private final Handler voiceProcessingHandler = new Handler();
private HandlerThread voiceProcessingHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("handler");

//the processing handler
private final Handler mainHandler = new Handler(voiceProcessingHandlerThread.getLooper(), new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        //do heavy processing 
        recognizerThread.getNewParamtersAfterFrameProcessed(msg.arg1);
    return true;
    }
});

the audio recorder thread
private final class RecognizerThread extends Thread {
      int value;

    //this method is then called from within processing thread when done
    public void getNewParamtersAfterFrameProcessed(int nread) {
         value = nread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    //the audio recording runnable
    }
}

...
// start the threads
recognizerThread = new RecognizerThread();
recognizerThread.start();

voiceProcessingHandlerThread.start();
```

But I am getting the error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing
>   doInBackground() Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create
>   handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

How can I do some heavy processing in a new thread while continuing recording the audio, and then return the values to the recorder thread, after the processing is done?

Comment: call `HandlerThread.start();` before getting its `Looper`

Comment: Try"new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())"